# how to select default formatter?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have `vscode` IDE, recently when I try to format my code vscode ask me to select which formatter to use.

[image]

Why? and How to select Prettier as default, but not remove `TypeScript and JavaScript Language Features` (This extension is bundled with Visual Studio Code. It can be disabled but not uninstalled).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using insiders, this is a recently bug (maybe), to solve the problem, you just need to update to latest insiders version:

```
Version: 1.33.0-insider (user setup)
Commit: 1876bd1d3805d632a9aa78fad47b2c3c555f6eec
Date: 2019-03-25T14:53:36.371Z
Electron: 3.1.6
Chrome: 66.0.3359.181
Node.js: 10.2.0
V8: 6.6.346.32
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.17763
```